# Change navigationItem's barButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsautoreleasepool

I have a UIViewController. I use the the rightBarButtonItem of the navigationItem as a "reload button". When the reload button is press, i use the leftBarButtonItem to display an Activity Indicator while the app is processing data to reload. Everything is ok up to here.
Here is some code:

```
- (void)initSpinner {
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: activityIndicator];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = activityButton;
}

- (void)spinBegin {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)spinEnd {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [self initSpinner];
     [super viewDidLoad];
    //more stuff going on here....
}
-(void) loadView{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshFeeds:)];
}
```

Now i was asked to change the logic a bit.
The rightBarButtonItem stays as is. The leftBarButtonItem is still there to display the activity Indicator, but when there is no processing it should display another button which will display a new view (for some info) when pressed.
So i did these changes:

```
- (void)initSpinner {
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: activityIndicator];
}

- (void)spinBegin {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = activityButton;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)spinEnd {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =infoBarButton; //= [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshFeeds:)] autorelease];
}
-(void) loadView{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshFeeds:)];

    if (infoBarButton == nil){
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];
        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 25, 25);

        // Initialize the UIBarButtonItem
        infoBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];

        // Set the Target and Action for aButton
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    }
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = infoBarButton;
}
```

Although it seems to be working (info button is there and when i press "reload" the activityIndicator takes its place till processing is done), i get the following in the debugger console:

```
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x15ef30 of class UINavigationItem autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1abd90 of class UIBarButtonItem autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1acb20 of class UIButton autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x15ef30 of class UINavigationItem autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1ad030 of class UIActivityIndicatorView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1ad030 of class UIActivityIndicatorView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1a8c40 of class UINavigationButton autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Object 0x941c of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
//MORE similar messages following...
```

What am i doing wrong? I hope someone out there can help...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using background threads to process your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're running the "reload" task in a background thread, and when it completes you call `spinEnd` from the background thread.  If the background thread doesn't have an autorelease pool in place, you will see those warnings.

Since you should only ever call `UIKit` methods from the main thread, you should call `spinEnd` by doing:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(spinEnd) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Hello @Daniel thank you for replying. I use another thread to start the spinner. If i use the same thread the spinner does not show up. This is the reload method:
`-(IBAction)refreshFeeds:(id)sender {
 if (stories){
  [stories release];
  stories = nil;
 }
 [self parseXMLFileAtURL:_theUrl];
}`
In the parseXMLFileAtURL i start the spinner by doing: `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinBegin) toTarget:self withObject:nil];` and in the `parserDidEndDocument` method of NSXMLParser i use `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinEnd) toTarget:self withObject:nil];` to stop it.

Comment: If i use your suggestion (both to start and stop the spinner) it never shows up. what am i missing?

Comment: It likely doesn't show up because you are downloading and parsing the XML synchronously by blocking the main thread, so UIKit never gets a chance to do any drawing (like showing the spinner).  What you should do is start the spinner normally, then do the download/parsing on a background thread, then when that completes, call back into the main thread to stop the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Are your properties being `retain`ed? You are doing and `alloc] init...` but aren't releasing them after assigning them to your properties. I'd suggest checking out the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)